# Laravel 6 route variable Controller method

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to make one route for all my ajax requests in laravel.
Currently what I have is:

```
Route::post('/ajax/{method}', 'AjaxController@index')->name('ajax-request');
```

Can I do something like this (using dynamic method name):

```
Route::post('/ajax/{method}', 'AjaxController@{method}')->name('ajax-request');
```

so for example when I call `/ajax/get_comments`, it will call `AjaxController@get_comments` method ?

Comment: So you have the `method` actions in your controller. Why don't you define them in your route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Route methods(`get`, `post` etc) can accept their's second parameter as ***string*** using the following pattern `ControllerName@methodName`.

You could retrieve the `{method}` parameter from *request path* and append it to Route method's second parameter. ie, like `'ControllerName@'. 'methodName'`

**Try the following** :

Assuming `{method}` would be your second segment in the request path. [If not change the value in the `segment()` parameter.]

Try the following:

```
Route::post('/ajax/{method}', 'AjaxController@'.(Request::segment('2')))->name('ajax-request');
```

**Please Note** :

If you choose to put URL parameter to be used as the method name there are some chance that, if a user is able to change the request path other than the specified one, run time exceptions will be thrown.

Consider the  following scenario :

Your `AjaxController` has only methods `get_comments()` and `get_deleted_comments()`.

If the request is `/ajax/get_comments` or `/ajax/get_deleted_comments` then their corresponding methods will work. But if request is something like `/ajax/get_xyz` and you dont have a method named `get_xyz` in your `AjaxController` then a `BadMethodCallException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You can add closure function to your route to achieve this one.

```
Route::get('ajax/{method}', function($method){

    $app = app();

    $controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController');

    return $controller->callAction($method, $parameters = array());

});
```

Now, call the `get_comments` method like:

```
localhost:8000/ajax/get_comments
```

NOTE: make sure your controller is inside `app/Http/Controller/` directory.

I hope you understand